# What is the logind process, and why is it running?

Tags: macos, root

I've recently noticed that a new process is up and running every time I start my computer - logind, running as root.

I'm unsure why this is happening - could it be a patch or so? I'm running a fairly vanilla version of OS X 10.8.4

Comment: Could be a [trojan](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20127094-263/tsunami-trojan-malware-bot-ported-to-os-x/) - the article gives some hints to check this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`logind` is a normal part of OS X. As @mt_ mentioned, there is a trojan that mimics it, but seeing a program by that name is entirely normal, not an indication of any problem.

If you are concerned that the normal `logind` has been replaced by a trojan, check /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.logind.plist, and make sure it refers to "/System/Library/CoreServices/logind", NOT "/usr/sbin/logind". See [the CNET article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20127094-263/tsunami-trojan-malware-bot-ported-to-os-x/) for more info.